# anyone knows how to get the counts of every element of a column in it self

Tags: r, count, dataframe

for example, this is my data

```
mydata
  v
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 2
6 3
```

is there any function that can generate a vector or column like

```
  v counts
1 1      2
2 1      2
3 2      3
4 2      3
5 2      3
6 3      1
```

I tried the method of `sum()`,but failed

```
mydata$counts <- sum(mydata$v == mydata$v)
```

Comment: `ave` might help here, like `ave(x,x,FUN=length)`

Comment: For future reference, the correct r tag is [tag:data.frame] and there's no need to embed r code in html snippet blocks, since html and r are unrelated. (These problems have been fixed on your post already.)

Comment: Also `library(data.table) ; setDT(mydata)[, counts := .N, by = v]`

Answer (score 4):

Another base R option with `ave`:

```
within(mydata, counts <- ave(v, v, FUN=length))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(group_by(mydata,v),count=(length(v)))
```

Comment: A more correct syntax would be probably `mydata %>% group_by(v) %>% mutate(counts = n())` or maybe `mydata %>% left_join(count(., v))` but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
mydata$counts <- with(mydata, table(v)[as.character(v)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ddply`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata, .(v), mutate, counts = length(v))

#  v counts
#1 1      2
#2 1      2
#3 2      3
#4 2      3
#5 2      3
#6 3      1
```

Or `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(mydata, mydata$v), 
        function(x){ x$counts = length(x$v); x}))

#    v counts
#1.1 1      2
#1.2 1      2
#2.3 2      3
#2.4 2      3
#2.5 2      3
#3   3      1
```

Answer (score -3):

```
> mydata
  v
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 2
6 3
```

I would use something like this:

```
as.data.frame(table(a))
```

`a Freq
1  1    2
2  2    3
3  3    1`

Comment: (Didn't downvote) but there is a `table` answer already, though your answer isn't matching the expected output...