# Count frequency of each element in vector

Tags: r, vector, count, frequency

I'm looking for a way to count the frequency of each element in a vector.

```
ex <- c(2,2,2,3,4,5)
```

Desired outcome:

```
[1] 3 3 3 1 1 1
```

Is there a simple command for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
rep(table(ex), table(ex))
# 2 2 2 3 4 5 
# 3 3 3 1 1 1
```

If you don't want the labels you can wrap in `as.vector()`

```
as.vector(rep(table(ex), table(ex)))
# [1] 3 3 3 1 1 1
```

I'll add (because it seems related somehow) that if you only wanted consecutive values, you could use `rle` instead of `table`:

```
ex2 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4)
rep(rle(ex2)$lengths, rle(ex2)$lengths)
# [1] 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 1 2 2
```

As pointed out in comments, for a large vector calculating a table can be expensive, so doing it only once is more efficient:

```
tab = table(ex)
rep(tab, tab)
# 2 2 2 3 4 5 
# 3 3 3 1 1 1
```

Comment: Also, for the `rle` one you can do `with(rle(ex), rep(lengths, lengths))` to avoid multiple `rle` calculations :)

Comment: Also, `ave(ex,ex,FUN=length)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ex <- c(2,2,2,3,4,5)    
outcome <- ave(ex, ex, FUN = length)
```

This is what [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail) suggested. Also similar to the answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280277/adding-counts-of-a-factor-to-a-dataframe?lq=1)